# How to rectify InvalidActiveXStateException in WPF?

Tags: wpf, exception

I am trying to make a WPF Application and using the Visio Controls. I have a dll named AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx and I refer it to instantiate an object of the type AxDrawingControl().
 Now as soon as I write this code:

```
AxDrawingControl objDrawControl=new AxDrawingControl();
```

and check the attributes of this object objDrawControl in the debug mode, I see this message: Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown.

Here is how it looks like: [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fed103f4d3.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fed103f4d3.jpg)

Please help me to get this thing resolved! Please!

I just realized the image isn't visible. So here is the link of the image showing the error message: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fed103f4d3.jpg

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? After calling the constructor you then have to call `CreateControl()` on the object.